# is there anything 3d software with pre-installed poses?

Tags: animation

I am looking for a 3d animation software that will speed up my posing and animation process.  I am presently using blender which allows me to define new poses. That not been what I want, I want a software where that if I want to animate a character that us working and latter jumping, I can simply search in the pre-installed post where walking is written, when I click working the character or their character begins to work with the required keyframe and when I search and click jump the character automatically jumps. if their is a software that has this features,  it will reduce the stress of posing almost everything.  So,  I will be happy if I am supported with an idea of accomplishing this or with a software that has this feature.

Comment: Even if this was a programming question, it's still off-topic. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Okey,  I have heard you. I will adobt your correction